# iOs8 Touch Injection programmatically

Tags: ios, ios8

I want to inject the touch programmatically on iOs device. I have code which works fine for < iOs7 using "GSTouchEvent" BUT not working for iOs7+.

I have also tried using IOHIDEvents but that also does not work for iOs8.

What I need is :
If I call something like this: postTouch(x, y, click);
It should generate the touch on iOs device screen at (x,y) position.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you need : https://github.com/iolate/SimulateTouch
It works well for ios8.1